# Incrementing sequence number udp sockets

Tags: java, sockets, bit-manipulation

I am implementing the server side of a UDP client-server program. I keep track of the expected sequence number in seq_num and calculate the sequence number recieved in the datagram in sequence_number. The program does not enter the if (sequence_number==seq_num) condition after the sequence number exceeds 127 though the values of seq_num and sequence_number are printed as 128. Any idea why this is happening? The code snippet is given below.

The first four bytes in the recieved packet contains the sequence number. This is compared with a counter seq_num which is incremented in the while loop. The if condition is not entered when seq_num reaches 128.

```
while(true){
     System.out.println("Waiting to receive packet");
    dg.receive(packet);
    buf = packet.getData();
    System.out.println("Received packet");
    Random rn =new Random();
    double p = rn.nextDouble();
    System.out.println(p);
    byte[] seqnumarray = new byte[4];
    for (int i=0; i<4 ; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(buf[i]);
        seqnumarray[i] = buf[i];
    }
    Integer sequence_number = java.nio.ByteBuffer.wrap(seqnumarray).getInt();
    System.out.println("seq num received is "+sequence_number);
    if (p > prob)
    {
        System.out.println("seq_num is " + seq_num);
        System.out.println("sequence_number is " + sequence_number);
        if(seq_num == sequence_number){
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your code is exceedingly convoluted. Please narrow down your question to the specific bit that's misbehaving, and clean up your formatting so it's easier to read.

Comment: Changed the code snippet to point to the exact location of the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you round-tripping things through a big `String` representation in the first place? If there really is a good reason to do so, you should put all of that in a single `format` statement. Also, have you checked that your `p > prob` condition is true?

Comment: How can I put all of them in one format statement? I thought I should operate on them one byte at a time.
The condition p>prob is true. I did check that.

Comment: Why the string at all? It's really unclear why you have it, except to very expensively "reconstitute" `sequence_number`.

Comment: Not using strings now. Converting it directly from the byte array format. It still gives the same error.

Comment: ...what type is `seq_num`?

Answer (score 2):

You're using the `Integer` wrapper class instead of an `int` primitive (which is actually what `ByteBuffer.getInt()` returns), and the standard Java rules about reference and value equality apply. As an optimization, the runtime interns the `Integer` values -128 to 127, so by accident using `==` works for these values, but for the general case, you need to use `equals`. Even better, just use the plain `int`.